# Getting a timestamp exception when I try to update an unrelated field using painless in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Im trying to run the following script

```
POST /data_hip/_update/1638643727.0
{
  "script":{
    "source":"ctx._source.avgmer=4;"
  }
}
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to parse field [@timestamp] of type [date] in document with id '1638643727.0'. Preview of field's value: '1.638642742E12'"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to parse field [@timestamp] of type [date] in document with id '1638643727.0'. Preview of field's value: '1.638642742E12'",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "failed to parse date field [1.638642742E12] with format [epoch_millis]",
      "caused_by" : {
        "type" : "date_time_parse_exception",
        "reason" : "Failed to parse with all enclosed parsers"
      }
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

this is strange because on queries (not updates) the date time is parsed fine.
The timestamp field mapping is as follows

```
"@timestamp": {
        "type":"date",
        "format":"epoch_millis"
},
```

I am running elasticsearch 7+

EDIT:
Adding my index settings

```
{
  "data_hip" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "routing" : {
          "allocation" : {
            "include" : {
              "_tier_preference" : "data_content"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "provided_name" : "data_hip",
        "creation_date" : "1638559533343",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "CHjkvSdhSgySLioCju9NqQ",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "7150199"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Im not running an ingest pipeline

Comment: Are your documents going through an ingest pipeline? Do you mind sharing your index settings?

Comment: I added my index settings.  I am not going through an ingest pipeline

Comment: ES is expecting epoch milliseconds (an integer) and seeing the string '1.638642742E12' instead. While the string is representing an integer in scientific notation, ES does not decode it to an integer and gets angry

Comment: Thanks Nate,  I notice all my numeric fields have quotes around the values.  But my mapping has dynamic set to false and I do have these fields set to integer or float.  So I thought that was a display thing.  Plus when I look at the date in a query it comes out as a real date.  See edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the scientific notation, the 'E12' suffix, being in a field that ES is expecting to be an integer.

Using this reprex:

```
PUT so_test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "ts": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "epoch_millis"
      }
    }
  }
}

# this works
POST so_test/_doc/
{
  "ts" : "123456789"
}

# this does not, throws the same error you have IRL
POST so_test/_doc/
{
  "ts" : "123456789E12"
}
```

I'm not sure how/where those values are creeping in, but they are there in the document you are passing to ES.